# Finding the Quadrant of a degree with python

Tags: python

```
def quad(degree):

    if degree <= '90':
        angle = 'Quadrant 1'
    else:
        if degree <= '180':
            angle = 'Quadrant 2'
        else:
            if degree <= '270':
                angle = 'Quadrant 3'
            else:
                if degree <= '360':
                    angle = 'Quadrant 4'

    return quad

print (quad ('100'))
```

executing lines 1 to 17 of "angle.py")

Why does it not tell me which quadrant it's in?

Comment: just for improvements on your code, Python has an `elif` keyword for these cases, and for your math, `angle = (degree % 360) // 90` will give you the quadrant number in a single line and will also handle values outside 0-360 range.

Answer (score 2):

You should return `angle` from the function not `quad`, When returning `quad` function instance is being returned, your code should be this:

```
def quad(degree):

    if degree <= 90:
        angle = 'Quadrant 1'
    else:
        if degree <= 180:
            angle = 'Quadrant 2'
        else:
            if degree <= 270:
                angle = 'Quadrant 3'
            else:
                if degree <= 360:
                    angle = 'Quadrant 4'

    return angle
print(quad(100))
```

In your code you were comparing strings(the numbers were in single quotes), now the above code compares numbers.

Comment: Oh wow can't believe I never caught that, Thank you now no matter what I change the print number to it still says "Quadrant 1"

Answer (score 1):

```
angle = int(input("Input angle: "))
basis = angle
angle %= 360.0
if (angle < 0):
  angle += 360.0;
quadrant = int((angle/90) % 4 + 1)
quadrantList = ["I", "II", "III", "IV"]
print("Angle",basis, "is in", "quadrant", quadrantList[quadrant-1])
```

Comment: A short explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is an error in pseudocode.
(I'm not gonna write the code for you on this one).

If you look at quadrants, each quadrant is 90 degrees. Therefor, it can be represented as a **MULTIPLE** of 90.

What you'd like to do is simple:
Divide the angle (as someone mentioned above, rename for clarity) / 90.
This will give you a value relative to the quadrant. 
100 = 1.11
180 = 2
etc...

You can then, use Floor Rounding (remove the decimals), to determine the quadrant number. Make sure to return the result, and not the original variable being passed :)

GLHF.